# How do I make my discord bot react with ✅ to the last message

Tags: javascript, node.js, discord, discord.js

I am in the process of programming a counting bot and want the bot to respond to the message with the emoji ✅ for every correct number. The bot was written in js.

I want the bot to respond to the right message with the emoji ✅.
This is the code snippet I have so far:

```js
let count = 1
let timeout

client.on('messageCreate', ({channel, content, member}) => {
  // Only do this for the counting channel of course
  // If you want to simply make this work for all channels called 'counting', you
  // could use this line:
  // if (client.channels.cache.filter(c => c.name === 'counting').has(channel.id))

  if (channel.id === channelid) {
    if (member.user.bot) return

    if (Number(content) === count + 1) {
      // ...increase the count
      count++     
      if (timeout) clearTimeout(timeout)

      // Add a new timeout
      timeout = setTimeout(
        // This will make the bot count and log all errors
        () => channel.send(++count).catch(console.error),
        // after 30 seconds
        30000
      )
    // If the message wasn't sent by the bot...
    } else if (member.id !== client.user.id) {
      // ...send a message because the person stuffed up the counting (and log all errors)
      channel.send(`${member} messed up!`).catch(console.error)
      // Reset the count
      count = 0
      // Reset any existing timeout because the bot has counted so it doesn't need to
      // count again
      if (timeout) clearTimeout(timeout)
    } else if (lastMsgAuthor && message.author.id === lastMsgAuthor) {
        message.delete();
    }
  }
});
```

Comment: that was `message.addReaction()` or something

Comment: Thx but wehn in do Thies that Error Pop Up 'message is not defined'

Comment: If you want the bot to react to a message, you can just use `message.react()`

Comment: use `<Message>.react()` to react to message ex. with your code: `content.react("✅")`

Comment: @KNguyen `content` is not a `Message` object, just a string so it doesn't have a `react()` method.

Answer (score 1):

You should use [`message.react('✅')`](https://discord.js.org/#/docs/discord.js/stable/class/Message?scrollTo=react). The problem is that there is no `message` object as you've already destructured it. Instead, you could name the argument `message` and destructure it as the first thing in your callback, like this:

```js
client.on('messageCreate', (message) => {
  const { channel, content, member } = message;

  if (channel.id === channelid) {
    // ...
```

And use the `message` object to send a reaction:

```js
if (Number(content) === count + 1) {
  message.react('✅').catch(console.error);
  count++;

  if (timeout)
    clearTimeout(timeout);
  // ...
```

You could also grab the `react()` method though, like this:

```js
client.on('messageCreate', ({ channel, content, member, react }) => {
  if (channel.id === channelid) {
    // ...
```

And then just call `react()`:

```js
if (Number(content) === count + 1) {
  react('✅').catch(console.error);
  count++;

  if (timeout)
    clearTimeout(timeout);
  // ...
```